# Не отображаются товары на сайте

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть страница Рекомендации, там все отображается, на страницу с товарами вставляю такой же код, только меняю название классов, пропадает footer, и все что после тоже. Подключаю CMS WordPress, с плагином custom field suite, делаю по уроку в ютубе.[image: страница с товарами]

```html
            <div class='cards-coll'>
                <div class='container-coll'>
                    <?php
                        $posts = get_posts( [
                            'numberposts' => 4,
                            'category_name' => '',
                            'orderby' => 'title',
                            'order' => 'ASC',
                            'post_type' => 'post',
                            'suppress_filter' => true
                        ] );
                        foreach($posts as $post){
                            setup_postdata($post);
                            ?>
                            <div class='card-coll'>
                            <div class='card-img'>
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('adv_thumbnail'); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class='card-text'><a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                            <p style="font-family: 'RobotoBold'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 800; font-size: 48px; color: #C3A4E8; padding-left: 35px;  margin-top: 5px;  margin-bottom: auto;" class='card-price'><?=CFS()->get('recom_price'); ?></p>
                            <div class='card-nall'>
                                <p><img src='<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img/nall.png' alt=''><?=CFS()->get('recom_nal'); ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      <?php
                        }
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                        ?>
 
                    


                </div>        
            </div>
```

Comment: `меняю название классов` - зачем? что за классы?

Comment: @DaemonHK менять классы, потому что я скопировала код, с выводом элементов, с другой страницы своего сайта, и разные стили и название классов, я уточнила, что это я меняла

Comment: я хочу узнать из за чего в общем может быть такая проблема